# Как обратиться к символу элемента массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Как обратиться к первой цифре каждого элемента массива?

```
let arr = ['424121321', '24121321','2321','524121321','624121321','724121321','5332']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать следующий метод:

`let x = arr[i].charAt(0);`

Comment: можно и просто `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = ['424121321', '24121321','2321','524121321','624121321','724121321','5332'];
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  console.log(arr[i][0]);
}
```

Если тип данных может быть не только строкой, а числом:

```
let arr = ['424121321', '24121321','2321','524121321','624121321','724121321','5332'];
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  console.log(String(arr[i])[0]);
}
```